# Why do string inputs break if you have a space

Tags: c++, string

I have just started learning C++ and I created the following code:

```cpp
std::string fName, lName;
std::cout << "Enter your first name" << std::endl ; 
std::cin >> fName ;
std::cout << "\nEnter your last name" << std::endl ; 
std::cin >> lName ;
std::cout << "\nHello " << fName << " " << lName ;
return 0;
```

But I noticed if I enter a name full name for fName i.e. "John Doe" lName get skipped but the code still prints out "Hello John Doe".

Could someone please explain why this behaviour occurs

Comment: The behavior occurs, because it is the default, that whitespaces cause text formatted extraction to stop.

Comment: Text input using streams like `std::cin` and the stream extraction operator `>>` will read *space delimited* input. So the input for `lName` isn't skipped. Try printing `fName` and `lName` separately.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thats cool behaviour! Would there be a way to avoid that happening though?

Comment: Read *lines* instead? With e.g. `std::getline`.